Get Xpath with Selenium in Python
Update
I want to get XPath in website to click by using Selenium. I find elements in Chrome, this Click have:
<span data-v-eb4b31da="" class="btn_claim">Claim Now</span>

Details is here:

I try many time, and try switch windows but I can get what I want. My code here:
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
service = Service() 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://web.telegram.org/") 
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button/span[text()='Claim Now']")


When i run code, the error is: "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button/span[text()='Claim Now']"}"
Thank for your help

We can't log into the site. Your XPath looks fine. Are you getting an error? If so, post the full error message as text in your question. Have you tested the locator in the browser to make sure that it's unique? Press F12 and type $x("//button/span[text()='Claim Now']"). Does it return only 1? Is the element in an IFRAME or shadow-root?

what did you get? Describe all details in question (not in comments). You could also check what you get in driver.page_source - maybe it gets different HTML. OR maybe it needs some time to load all elements on page. It may needs time.sleep() or Waits

BTW: the newest Selenium can download driver without using webdriver_manager and it allows to use shorter code driver = webdriver.Chrome()

I updated, i think it is a popup windows and try to switch windows (driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])) . But i can get this button in driver.page_source. @JeffC

You didn't answer all of my questions.
